# Intershop rest token timeout

Tags: rest, intershop

About the rest token. I notice that it expires rather quickly, is there a way to set the expiration time for rest token? I couldn't find documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the same as the session timeout and you can change it with property "`intershop.session.TimeOut`" in `appserver.properties`

see
com.intershop.component.rest.internal.auth.TokenImpl.getExpirationDate()